# When i called 3rd parti web service in C# then showing error

Tags: c#, asp.net

web service url is : http://xyx:80/soa-infra/aaa/bbb/cccc/ddd_ep?WSDL

Error :

> System.Web.HttpException: Failed to map the path '/TestService/The
>   request failed with an empty response.'

.

Comment: Show your code that you used to call the web service, please.

Comment: The URL for the web service won't have ?WSDL on the end. That URL returns the web service definition of the service. Try without that.

Comment: callig web service:

WebReference.qcsverifycoostatusbpel_ep req = new WebReference.qcsverifycoostatusbpel_ep();

                 WebReference.process process1 = new WebReference.process();
                 process1.cooNumber = "001";

                 req.process(process1);

                 Response.Write(req.process(process1).ToString());

                 WebReference.processResponse res = new WebReference.processResponse();    

                 Response.Write(res.responseStatus.ToString());

Comment: Please help me anyone